# How to dynamically configure the OAuth2 authorization parameters of HTTP Request Connector in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule4

I am recently working on a project which requires me to create a generic HTTP request connector that can be used to call the REST APIs that use OAuth2 as authorization protocol. In mule 4, when we call API using HTTP Request connector, we have to configure the authorization parameters like "token URL", "Authorization URL", "callback URL", "client id" and "client secret".

To make the HTTP request generic, I did not pre-built these parameters in configuration, but make these parameters refer to mule variable passed in at runtime. However, when I tested it and passed in the value of these parameters at runtime, I got error like this:

**Already exists a listener matching that path and methods. Listener matching DefaultPathAndMethodRequestMatcher{path='/callback1/', methodRequestMatcher='MethodRequestMatcher{methods=[GET]}'} new listener DefaultPathAndMethodRequestMatcher{path='/callback1/', methodRequestMatcher='MethodRequestMatcher{methods=[GET]}'}**

I am a little confused by the error message because I can make sure that in my mule app, there is only one HTTP listener with "/callback1" as path.

I have no idea how to dynamically configuring OAuth parameters of HTTP connector in mule. Could anyone help me with this? How can I make the generic connector workable.

my mule app configuration XML is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:oauth="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth" xmlns:os="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os/current/mule-os.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth/current/mule-oauth.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="3b3ca049-7637-4800-a715-93738c0c2532" >
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" port="443" >
            <http:authentication >
                <oauth:authorization-code-grant-type localCallbackConfig="HTTP_Listener_config" localCallbackConfigPath="/callback1" externalCallbackUrl="http://localhost:8081/callback1" localAuthorizationUrl="http://localhost:8081/login" authorizationUrl="https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth" clientId="#[vars.connection_config.clientId]" clientSecret="#[vars.connection_config.clientSecret]" tokenUrl="#[vars.connection_config.tokenUrl]"/>
            </http:authentication>
        </http:request-connection>
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="config" doc:id="5035fd45-5282-4431-8dd0-1da486d45cb4" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="d1aa572c-c3fa-4c3a-abb3-4a89004bdb70" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/config" allowedMethods="POST"/>
        <os:store doc:name="Store" doc:id="79361aec-82fd-410c-9dec-2169177fe7fb" key="connection_config"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="general-connector" doc:id="cf090731-a62f-4dc7-83a6-dd27f920143c" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="3db0841f-831c-46ea-8bbd-dcfc4d1307f5" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/connect" allowedMethods="POST"/>
        <set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="f2144061-06d5-4438-a86a-1ff27d139216" variableName="product_data"/>
        <os:retrieve doc:name="Retrieve" doc:id="f7b9e03f-be5c-474e-954c-3fc0b7d9eddf" key="connection_config" target="connection_config" />
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" doc:id="5b0abbf8-9d57-4f78-8511-e0ad85e97cd1" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" url="#[vars.connection_config.url]">
            <http:body><![CDATA[#[vars.product_data]]]></http:body>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

There are two flows in my app. the flow "config" is to receive authentication params and store them in mule app.
My request payload to call the mule app "config" flow are as below. These will be stored in mule app and when I

```
{
    "url": "https://graph.facebook.com:443/v7.0/******/batch",
    "clientId": "***************",
    "clientSecret": "***********",
    "tokenUrl" : "https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/oauth/access_token",
    "authorizationUrl": "https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth"
}
```

The second flow named as "general-connector" is to retrieve these authentication and authorization params and set them as mule variables, and then use HTTP Request connector to make API calls to external system.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add to your question the HTTP configuration and flow in XML textual representation (not screenshots of the UI).

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I've added more details about configuration XML file in the question body.